# How are these two parametrizations of the Pascal PMF related?

Tags: probability, negative-binomial-distribution

On Wikipedia, the Pascal PMF is written as
$$p(k)=\begin{pmatrix}r+k-1\\k\end{pmatrix}p^k(1-p)^r\tag1\label1$$
where $r$ is the number of failures before the $k$th success and $p$ is the success probability. Here $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

In my book, the Pascal PMF is written as
$$p_{Y_k}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}t-1\\k-1\end{pmatrix}p^k(1-p)^{t-k}\tag2\label2$$
where the total time $t\in\{k,k+1,k+2,\ldots\}$.

The total time is the number of successes plus the number of failures so $t=k+r$. If we substitute this in $\ref2$, we get
$$p_{Y_k}(k+r)=\begin{pmatrix}r+k-1\\k-1\end{pmatrix}p^k(1-p)^r$$

How can we get to $\ref1$?

Comment: An interesting case is $r=0$. $\ref1$ gives $0$ but $\ref2$ gives $p^t$.

Comment: You should change the notation because in (1) $k$ denotes a value and $r$ is a parameter, while in (2) $t$ is a value and $k$ is the parameter. So rewrite (2) replacing $k$ by $r$. Another difference is that $p$ and $1-p$ are exchanged between (1) and (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The notations are not the same in (1) and (2)**. If

- $r$ is the number of failures
- $p$ is the success probability
- $N$ is the random number of successes
- $M$ is the random number of draws

(1) is the pdf of $N$:
$$\mathbb{P}(N=k)={r+k-1 \choose k}\,p^k(1-p)^r\mathbb{I}_{\{0,1,\ldots\}}(k)\tag{1}$$
and (2) is the pdf of $M$:
$$\mathbb{P}(M=\ell)={\ell-1 \choose r-1}\,p^{\ell-r}(1-p)^r\mathbb{I}_{\{r,r+1,\ldots\}}(\ell)\tag{2}$$
They are coherent since, when $\ell=k+r$
$${r+k-1 \choose k}={r+k-1 \choose r-1}={\ell-1 \choose r-1}$$
and hence
$$\mathbb{P}(N=k)=\mathbb{P}(M=\ell)$$